# How to programmatically create an NSComboBox

Tags: ios, jcombobox, nscombobox

i have a view. how do i create a NSComboBox programmatically

Comment: `NSComboBox` is not available in iOS. You might have to create your own custom dropdown implementation for that.

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox like Mac OS X is not possible in iOS X. 
You can do a workaround. Use the image as backgroud(like combobox background) and user other controls on it like textfield, buttons etc.